# The standard Eclipse 'Find/Replace' dialog without Replace functionality

Tags: java, eclipse, find

I have to create a dialog for searching in views which contain trees with non-editable nodes. The standard Eclipse 'Find/Replace' functionality came to my mind. Is the related dialog class accessible? And if yes, is it flexible enough so that I can deactivate the Replace functionality so that it works only in Find mode?

P.S. I've downloaded the code from an open-source project. There is the same functionality I need there. But they have implemented the dialog and the Find functionality from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create and run a [FindReplaceAction](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/texteditor/FindReplaceAction.html), which in turn will open the dialog. Whether or not replace is enabled depends on the active viewpart. Whenever the active viewpart changes, the dialog will be [notified of a new IFindReplaceTarget](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/eclipse/eclipse-3.5.2/org/eclipse/ui/texteditor/FindReplaceDialog.html#updateTarget%28org.eclipse.jface.text.IFindReplaceTarget,%20boolean,%20boolean%29), and depending on that enable/disable editing features.